# Angular 6: Passing Observable response to another Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, rxjs

I have problem with fetching the web API output using observable in angular typescript.

I'd like to fetch the value that will be returned by the first observable then pass its value to another observable. So far, this is what I have written.

```
let output: any;
let output2: any;

_httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller')
  .subscribe((output_1) => {
    output = output_1;
  });

alert(output);

_httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller2'+output)
  .subscribe((output_2) => {
    output2 = output_2;        
  });
alert(output2);
```

I place an alert function below each observable subscribed to check the output returned of each response.

but when I execute it and check the output in the alert box, it gives undefined value to each.

how can I force observable to give the output that will come from my web API?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use an operator such as [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) which per documentation "Maps to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values". Using `switchMap` it will switch to the 2nd `HttpClient` call mapping the first observable, when the source of the first `HttpClient` calls emits. If a new initial/outer request is executed, it will cancel the in-flight/in-process request.

Keep in mind, the way your `alert()` statements are set up, they will simply not work as `alert()` will execute before the requests have completed, hence the `undefined`. You'd need to execute `alert()` or similar within `subscribe` or utilize operators such as `do`/`tap` to ensure the data has actually been returned.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

_httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(output => _httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller2' + output))
  )
  .subscribe(output2 => alert(output2));
```

If you need to save the outputs to some local class property, you can utilize [do/tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) to perform an action before/after data is returned/mapped/processed.

```
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

_httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller')
  .pipe(
    tap(output => {
        console.log(output);
        this.output = output;            
    }),
    switchMap(output => _httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller2' + output)),
    tap(output2 => {
        console.log(output2);
        this.output2 = output2;            
    })
  )
  .subscribe(output2 => alert(output2));
```

Comment: Actually, switchMap does exactly the opposite of ensuring the first request is complete. If the first request is not completed before the next emission, it will actually be cancelled in favor of the second request.

Comment: I'll update the language of the answer. Either way, the requestor needed a simple operator to chain sequential HttpClient calls together, which is what switchMap demonstrated. If you want to show examples with mergeMap, concatMap, exhaustMap, etc feel free to do so.

Comment: @ggradnig If you felt this was wrong, a more helpful response would be to show other approaches to sequentially making `HttpClient` calls or even handling errors from the first `HttpClient` call using operators in the context of the requester's question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, the anwser is right of course, but the subtle detail about switchMap may cause issues if not understood correctly. For example, if a write operation follows after the switchMap statement, it would be cancelled, making the result of the API call lost forever. Anyways, you can make sequential calls with mergeMap as well, so this alternative could also be mentioned.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky: How would your code adjust if  I need to repeatedly do operation in second API call like this
    switchMap(output => _httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/mycontroller2' + output[i])),

were output[i] is the value emitted from the first API call?
 I mean how do I repeat the switchMap operation depending on the values passed by first api call?

Comment: @Mike I'd really recommend to create a question to help your issue answered. That being said, based on the snippet you provided, are you attempting to execute async actions within a loop. I'd recommend to utilize operators such as forkJoin, concatAll, or combineAll. I've used [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), passing in an array of `Observable<T>` and then `map()` to transform the resulting array output as necessary. It will depends on your use case, but creating a question would give you the best support. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue. As written above, `switchMap` results in cancelled http requests, and `mergeMap` results in redundant http requests. Isn't there a safer alternative that just makes only the 2 necessary requests?

Answer (score 5):

For completeness of the accepted answer, other alternatives to `switchMap` should be mentioned as well.

In contrast to `switchMap`, the `mergeMap` (also called `flatMap`) operator will **NOT** be cancelled if the "outer observable" emits a second time before the "inner observable" completes. This may not be important in the case of `HttpClient.get`, because it typically only emits once, thus never triggering the inner observable again.

However, be aware of the difference between `switchMap` and `mergeMap` when continuing working with RxJS operators, especially when dealing with a sequential stream of data.

Comment: `mergeMap` is indeed not cancelling http requests, but results in redundant http requests, as it will issue the outer request with the old value, and when it gets the new value it will issue another one.